# I am looking for some ways to monitor application logs live on the web page

Tags: logging, monitor

If you happen to know some jquery perl or php plugin that I can add to my web page to monitor a logfile live like tail -f please let me know.

Many thanks !!
Tonya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a java/php plugin called Webtailx which lets you monitor a logfile live on the web, here is the link :

http://webtailx.sourceforge.net/?id=demo

Comment: Thanks, I tried to configure it but showing last few lines of the php script that it calls instead of the logfile ? any idea why?

Comment: Make sure that php script starts with <?php